# Streamlit python AxiosError on PCAP file upload

Tags: python, axios, streamlit

I am kind of new to streamlit python and I have been trying to build an app to parse a PCAP file from wireshark and display fields in streamlit appropriately.

How ever I am kind of really stuck at the 1st place in uploading the file, even though it looks fairly simple. I am able to upload a text file and a few excel files successfully however I hit AxiosError each time I upload a PCAP file. Below is the code snippet and error screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmYeu.png)

My python version is 3.10.7 and Streamlit version is 1.29.0

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Choose a PCAP file to create entry in registry", accept_multiple_files=True)
```

I have tried on different streamlit versions like 1.30, 1.31 and 1.32 but the same error. Please note I have not yet deployed my code and I am running it locally.

I have also tried running the script using command "streamlit run '..venv\UE Cap\Create.py' --server.enableXsrfProtection False --server.enableCOR
S False" but to no avail.